# The scheduled job hasn't been executed automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I'm using Hangfire 1.7.11 and this [filter](https://gist.github.com/odinserj/a8332a3f486773baa009), but I changed the fingerprint format to use a [SHA256Hash](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=netcore-3.1) instead.

```
protected static string GetFingerprint(Job job)
{
    string parameters = string.Empty;
    if (job.Args != null)
    {
        parameters = string.Join(".", job.Args);
    }
    if (job.Type == null || job.Method == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    var fingerprint = String.Format(
        FingerprintFormat,
        job.Type.FullName,
        job.Method.Name,
        parameters);

    return fingerprint.ComputeSHA256Hash();
}
```

I don't know why hangfire was not executing **scheduled** jobs.
I'm scheduling the job like that:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule<Job>(s => s.Execute(Id), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

- My database is a SQL Server Express running on AWS;
- My frontend and backend are in the same server;
- I have a running server.
- The recurring jobs looks like ok;

You can see the problem in the picture below:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Theses jobs are been scheduled by another application though.
Using the same idea:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule<Job>(s => s.Execute(Id), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

I have a staging environment using the same database server but on a different database. It works, but for the production one, I have much more jobs to process.

**EDIT 2**

Yesterday I dropped the database and today it is working well. We are using AWS ECS Fargate and Autoscaling. Sometimes some servers are been adding when necessary. I don´t know if it can be a problem.

Comment: what errors are you getting and what happens when you have breakpoints in the code that should fire?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it locally. When I enqueue it manually it works. Should it log?